# Неправильно отображается подключенный шрифт WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Некорректно отображается шрифт Font Awesome 6 (квадраты) в приложении при дебаге.

Я подключил в проект шрифт Font Awesome 6, поместив файл .otf в проект. Далее настроил всё по инструкциям из интернетов.

В итоге, **шрифт корректно отображается**, НО, почему-то, **ТОЛЬКО** **в VisualStudio** **в предпросмотре** **окна** при редакторе XAML.

**При дебаге приложения, шрифт отображается неправильно** (отображаются квадраты).

Путь прописан правильно, а сам файл шрифта добавлен в проект (т.е. он есть не только в папке Fonts, но и в самом VisualStudio т.е. прописан в файле .csproj ).

Что я делал пытаясь решить проблему:

1. Почистил проект/решение через VisualStudio
2. Вручную почистил проект/решение удалая файлы
3. Переподключил шрифт к проекту
4. Создал новый, пустой проект WPF, где добавил шрифт и всего 1 элемент на главное окно
5. Запустил проект (полноценный и новый пустой) на другом компьютере с Windows 11 (изначально Windows 10).
6. Попробовал собрать проект (полноценный и новый пустой) как релиз
7. Установил шрифт Font Awesome 6
8. Изменил расширение шрифта с .otf на .ttf (не ну а чё, а вдруг)

Короче **ничего не помогло**. При любом раскладе приложение не отображается шрифт нормально, но при этом всегда в редакторе этот шрифт отображается корректно.

[image: Предпросмотр окна при редактировании в Visual Studio]

[image: Окно при дебаге]

[image: Шрифт скачан с официального сайта]

Код окна:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.Main.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Main"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="txtbox" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Text="&#xf0c8; &#xf28d; &#xf2bd;" 
               FontSize="60" Foreground="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Код App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Project.Main.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.Main"
         StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/Project.Main;component/Fonts/#Font Awesome 6 Free Regular</FontFamily>
</Application.Resources>
```

*Я также пробовал и другие способы задать путь к шрифту (а вдруг поможет):*

```
<!-- 1) <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/Project.Main;component/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#Font Awesome 6 Free Regular</FontFamily>
2) <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">pack://application;,,,/Fonts/#Font Awesome 6 Free Regular</FontFamily>
3) <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">pack://application;,,,/Fonts/FontAwesome.otf#Font Awesome 6 Free Regular</FontFamily> -->
```

---

Ещё раз подчеркну, что **шрифт** нормально **отображается ТОЛЬКО В ПРЕДПРОСМОТРЕ** внутри **Visual Studio**.

### **После сборки приложения (при дебаге или релизе) шрифт не отображается.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что я сделал, чтобы всё заработало, проект WPF .NET 6:

1. Положил нужные мне шрифты в папку **/Fonts** в проекте

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. У каждого файла шрифта выставил **Build Action: Resource**

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В **App.xaml** добавил `FontFamily`:

   ```xml
   <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <FontFamily x:Key="MyFontKey">./Fonts/#MyFontName</FontFamily>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
   ```

   Где `MyFontName` - внутреннее имя шрифта (не файла, но может совпадать).
4. Использовал в разметке окна вот так:

   ```xml
   <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFontKey}" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
   ```

---

Кстати, я бы для Windows 10+ приложения использовал родные виндовые иконки из шрифта **Segoe MDL2 Assets**. Этот шрифт по умолчанию установлен в системе и его не надо запихивать в само приложение. Подробности читайте [в документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font). Конечно, если вы планируете запускать приложение под Window 8 и старше, то шрифт всё равно придётся встраивать показанным выше способом.

Comment: Помогло выставление Build Action - Resource. До этого было Содержание